# Parcelable class does not make a parcelable object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcel

I am trying to save an ArrayList of objects (List shelfItems) in the bundle to retrieve it next time the activity is opened.

(the activity gets info from firestore and I want to decrease reads and take away loading time each time the activity is opened).

but i get this error message:

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("key", shelfItems);
```

"putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)' in 'android.os.Bundle' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.util.List)"

This is my object class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ShelfItem implements Parcelable{


    private String mTitle;
    private String mAuthor;
    private String mThumbnail;
    private long mRating;
    private long mEndDate;
    private long mBeginDate;
    private String mId;
    private long mPages;
    private boolean mVisible;

    //make ShelfItem object
    public ShelfItem(String title, String author, String thumbnail, long rating, long beginDate, long endDate, String id, long pages, boolean visible) {
        mTitle = title;
        mAuthor = author;
        mThumbnail = thumbnail;
        mRating = rating;
        mBeginDate = beginDate;
        mEndDate = endDate;
        mId = id;
        mPages = pages;
        mVisible = visible;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return mAuthor;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return mThumbnail;
    }

    public long getRating() {
        return mRating;
    }

    public long getBeginDate() {
        return mBeginDate;
    }

    public long getEndDate() {
        return mEndDate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public long getPages() {
        return mPages;
    }

    public boolean getVisible() {
        return mVisible;
    }


    public ShelfItem(Parcel in) {
        mId = in.readString();
        mTitle = in.readString();
        mAuthor = in.readString();
        mThumbnail = in.readString();
        mBeginDate = in.readLong();
        mEndDate = in.readLong();
        mPages = in.readLong();
        mVisible = in.readByte() != 0;
        mRating = in.readLong();

    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(mId);
        out.writeString(mTitle);
        out.writeString(mAuthor);
        out.writeString(mThumbnail);
        out.writeLong(mBeginDate);
        out.writeLong(mEndDate);
        out.writeLong(mPages);
        out.writeByte((byte) (mVisible ? 1 : 0));
        out.writeLong(mRating);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ShelfItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ShelfItem>() {
        public ShelfItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ShelfItem(in);
        }

        public ShelfItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ShelfItem[size];
        }
    };

}
```

and this is how I try to save the list:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("key", shelfItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we learn Java, we're taught to use the *interface type* (`List`) instead of the *implementation type* (`ArrayList`) when we declare our variables. You probably have code somewhere that looks like this:

```
List<ShelfItem> shelfItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, in the particular case of `Bundle` and saving lists, you **must** use `ArrayList` specifically, and not any `List` in general.

If I'm right, and your list is declared like I've shown above, just change it to explicitly use `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ShelfItem> shelfItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you're getting the list from somewhere else, and you can't control the implementation type of it, you can construct a `new ArrayList` when you need to save it:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<ShelfItem> toSave = new ArrayList<>(shelfItems);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("key", toSave);
}
```